# Bank Queue Simulation with multiple customer services in c

Tags: c, queue

i have this assignment where I should make a queue program that count how many customers that served by each customer services in the end (this program has 2 customer services). I try with this code, but when i try to print the cs->count, it gave nothing to the screen.

For the queue, i used the general linked list queue and I'm pretty sure it has nothing wrong with it.

The first code i have is this adt structure

```
typedef struct{
  int ID;
  int time;
  int count;
  bool serving;
}employee;

typedef struct{
  char ID[3];
  int code;
  int arrivalTime;
  int timeNeeded;
  employee servedBy;
}nasabah;
```

and the modules for this adt are:

```
nasabah inputNasabah(nasabah *n) // to initialize customer's data
{
  printf("Customer's ID : ");
  scanf("%s", (*n).ID);
  printf("Customer's need (type '1' for teller or '2' for Customer Service) : ");
  scanf("%d", &((*n).code));
  printf("Enter your arrvial time : ");
  scanf("%d", &((*n).arrivalTime));
  printf("Transaction time needed : ");
  scanf("%d", &((*n).timeNeeded));

  printf("\n");

  return *n;
}
```

edit : now i think the problem starts here, i seriously don't know why it doesn't run like how it supposed to be..

```
void csInit(employee *a, employee *b) //to initialize cs's data
{
   a->ID = 1;
   a->time = 0;
   a->count = 0;
   a->serving = false;

   b->ID = 2;
   b->time = 0;
   b->count = 0;
   b->serving = false;
}
```

and this one (the one that i think give the problem). This module is used to assign which customer services are served the customers and how many customers that customer service served. My logic are the very first customer will going to the "a" (first customer service) and a->serving will true, and the next customer will be at "b" (second customer service) since the "a" is not yet available (assuming the first and the second customer has a same arrival time) and b->serving will be true as well. And then the third customer come and will be served by one customer service that has the smallest time (by looking at a->time or b->time)

```
void servedByCS(nasabah *n, employee *a, employee *b) 
{
  csInit(a, b);

  if(a->serving == false)
  {
    n->servedBy = *a;
    a->time = a->time + n->timeNeeded;
    a->count = a->count + 1;
    a->serving = true;
  }
  else if(a->serving == true)
  {
    if(a->time > b->time)
    {
        n->servedBy = *b;
        b->time = b->time + n->timeNeeded;
        b->count = b->count + 1;
        b->serving = true;
    }

    if(a->time < b->time)
    {
        a->serving = false;
        n->servedBy = *a;
        a->time = a->time + n->timeNeeded;
        a->count = a->count + 1;
        a->serving = true;
    }
   }

   if (b->serving == true)
   {
     if (b->time < a->time)
     {
        b->serving = false;
     }
   }    
}
```

and finally my main driver contain :

```
int main()
{
  nasabah *n;
  antre cs; //queue for customer 

  int i;
  int amount = 0;
  node a;

  employee *cs1, *cs2; //since there are two customer service

  printf("Input the queue lenghth : ");
  scanf("%d", &amount);

  n = (nasabah *) malloc(amount * sizeof(nasabah));

  cs = CreateQueue(); //creating queue 

  for(i = 0; i < amount; i++)
  {
      *n = inputNasabah(n + i);
      enQueue(cs, *n); //inputting customer's data into the queue
  }

  while(!isEmpty(cs))
  {
     a = deQueue(cs); //dequeue from the first customer so it can be proceed to see which customer service will be served.
     servedByCS(&a.info, cs1, cs2); //i think i got this one wrong so the program didn't work
  }

  printf("%d", cs1->count); //i try to print how many customers are served by the cs1 (first customer service), but it didn't work.

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to add a `\n` in your `printf`

Comment: thank you for answering, but it's still not working

Comment: `char ID[3];` likely too small.  Try `char ID[300];`

Comment: thankyou for answeing, but i don't think it's the problem since i only need a small ID like 001, 045..

Comment: 001 does not fit in `char[3]` because you have no space for the null terminator.  A three-character string requires `char[4]`.

Comment: thankyou, but i've tried to changed it as suggested, still it's not work for

Comment: You never malloc memory for cs1 and cs2.
Your loop on `n` is weird, queue code is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issues were:

- employees are not allocated
- servedByCS if structure was complexe and not working 2 customer at the same time, else was missing

I have added the queue and nasabah are inserted ordered by their arrival time.

I remove serving field as it is useless
I have changed some fields from value to pointer

Missing, check values from scanf, check malloc, free the malloc memory

```
typedef struct{
    int ID;
    int time;
    int count;
}employee;

typedef struct nasabah nasabah;

struct nasabah{
    char ID[64];
    int code;
    int arrivalTime;
    int timeNeeded;
    employee *servedBy;
    nasabah *next;
};

static nasabah* inputNasabah(nasabah *n) // to initialize customer's data
{
    printf("Customer's ID : ");
    scanf("%s", n->ID);
    printf("Customer's need (type '1' for teller or '2' for Customer Service) : ");
    scanf("%d", &n->code);
    printf("Enter your arrival time : ");
    scanf("%d", &n->arrivalTime);
    printf("Transaction time needed : ");
    scanf("%d", &n->timeNeeded);
    printf("\n");

    return n;
}
static void employeeInit(employee *e, int id)
{
    e->ID = id;
    e->time = 0;
    e->count = 0;
}


static void serve(nasabah *n, employee *e) {
    n->servedBy = e;
    e->count++;
    if (n->arrivalTime > e->time) {
        /* if customer arrived after the employee has finished */
        e->time = n->arrivalTime + n->timeNeeded;
    } else {
        e->time += n->timeNeeded;
    }
}

static void servedByCS(nasabah *n, employee *a, employee *b)
{
    serve(n, a->time <= b->time ? a : b);
}

static void addNasabah(nasabah **root, nasabah *n) {
    nasabah *current = *root;
    if (!current || n->arrivalTime < current->arrivalTime) {
        n->next = current;
        *root = n;
        return;
    }
    while (current->next && current->next->arrivalTime < n->arrivalTime) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    n->next = current->next;
    current->next = n;
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    int amount = 0;
    nasabah *nasabahs = NULL;

    employee *cs1 = malloc(sizeof(employee));
    employee *cs2 = malloc(sizeof(employee));
    employeeInit(cs1, 1);
    employeeInit(cs2, 2);

    printf("Input the queue length : ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);

    for(i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        nasabah *n = malloc(sizeof(nasabah));
        inputNasabah(n);
        addNasabah(&nasabahs, n);
    }
    for (nasabah *n = nasabahs; n; n=n->next) {
        servedByCS(n, cs1, cs2);
    }

    printf("%d\n", cs1->count);

    return 0;
}
```

Tested with

```
Input the queue length : 3
Customer's ID : 1
Customer's need (type '1' for teller or '2' for Customer Service) : 1
Enter your arrival time : 0
Transaction time needed : 10

Customer's ID : 2
Customer's need (type '1' for teller or '2' for Customer Service) : 1
Enter your arrival time : 1
Transaction time needed : 3

Customer's ID : 3
Customer's need (type '1' for teller or '2' for Customer Service) : 1
Enter your arrival time : 6
Transaction time needed : 5

1
```

And

```
Input the queue length : 5
Customer's ID : 1
Customer's need (type '1' for teller or '2' for Customer Service) : 1
Enter your arrival time : 0
Transaction time needed : 10

Customer's ID : 2
Customer's need (type '1' for teller or '2' for Customer Service) : 1
Enter your arrival time : 7
Transaction time needed : 2

Customer's ID : 3
Customer's need (type '1' for teller or '2' for Customer Service) : 1
Enter your arrival time : 2
Transaction time needed : 6

Customer's ID : 4
Customer's need (type '1' for teller or '2' for Customer Service) : 1
Enter your arrival time : 8
Transaction time needed : 5

Customer's ID : 5
Customer's need (type '1' for teller or '2' for Customer Service) : 1
Enter your arrival time : 9
Transaction time needed : 2

2
```

Comment: hello, thank you so much for correcting my code as well. I'm really sorry because I've just found your answer now. Again, thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: If the answer is good you can mark it as resolved, if not don't hesitate to point an issue, will be happy to try to help